# How to reproduce this sliding effect?

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of learning jQuery, and I've been trying to reproduce this effect :
http://www.frenchtouchseduction.com/test-2.html

** edit : (for the sake of clarity : the sliding thing is what i'm interested in, don't mind the "hover circle on picture on hover" thingy)

I'm not even sure how I should describe it : my first guess was "sliding doors", but apparently, it's something else.

Here's what i've done so far :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul li .img").hover(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
})
```

```css
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

.wrapper { 
  width: 700px; 
  margin: 20px auto; 
}

ul { 
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;  
}

ul li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  font-size: 10px; 
  background: #F5F5F5; 
  color: #000; 
  font-size: 0;
}

.img { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block; 
}
    
.texte { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  display: none; 
  background: #F06; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
    
.active { 
  width: 200px; 
}

.active .texte { 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
      <div class="texte">1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
      <div class="texte">2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></div>
      <div class="texte">3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the result of my attempts : http://jsfiddle.net/77Lrm/

Somehow, I can't figure out how to get this slide-out / slide-in behaviour.

What am I missing ? Is there any specific library I should include not to reinvent the wheel, or is it something I can easily code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code:

1. You need to set active on the `$(this).parent()` of the event, not on `$(this)` directly since it is the .img getting the event
2. You can't use `display:none` if you want to animate that element.
3. You can let the LI grow automatically, just change the width of the text you want to show

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/77Lrm/4/

Comment: Thank you very much for both the explanation AND the solution, works like a charm ! (I was close !)